# How to use render and redirect together in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My controller has before action event which check for some parameter based on the redirects to the method

```
before_action :call_method

def call_method
  redirect_to action: process_it, status: 302, params: request.query_parameters and return if params[:navigate]
end

def process_it
  render json: {success:'activity recorded'} and return
end
```

Getting error 
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"

```
Wanted this {success:'activity recorded'} to be printed
```

What wrong i am doing here

Answer (score 0):

Because you call before_action for every request, also for `process_it`. Add except section to `before_action`:

```rb
before_action :call_method, except: :process_it
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to action: process_it ...` - try action name symbol `:process_it` instead of calling the method

Comment: can you give me sample?

Comment: @KunalVashist `redirect_to action: :process_it`, without `:` it's a ruby method call

Comment: getting Internal Server Error now